# facebook login Service not registered

Tags: android, facebook

When I use Facebook Login in our app, I met the question.Sometimes I signIn, it will crash with this error. I searched the similar quetion but not understand very well.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Service not registered: com.facebook.login.GetTokenClient@1ab2a49b
                                                                      at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1110)
                                                                      at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:2190)
                                                                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:571)
                                                                      at com.facebook.internal.PlatformServiceClient.handleMessage(PlatformServiceClient.java:145)
                                                                      at com.facebook.internal.PlatformServiceClient$1.handleMessage(PlatformServiceClient.java:62)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

This is my code: It's  `initLogin()` in `onCreate()` method

```
 private void initLogin() {
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                  String mToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
                  if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(mToken)){
                    GraphRequest graphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                           if (response.getError() != null) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "FB: parse info error!");
                                onLoginFail(Constants.LOGIN_FACEBOOK);
                            } else {
                                LogHelper.d(TAG, "Object:" + object.toString() + ",Response:" + response);
                                loginPresenter.startLoginFacebook( loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken(),
                                object.optString("id"), object.optString("name"),
                                object.optString("picture"), object.optString("email"));
                           }
                        }

                    });
                    Bundle mParameters = new Bundle();
                    mParameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,picture,birthday");
                    graphRequest.setParameters(mParameters);
                    graphRequest.executeAsync();
                 }else {
                     onfailed();
                 }

             }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                LogHelper.d(TAG,"User cancel to login FB。");
            }

             @Override
             public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                onfailed();
            }

                private void onfailed() {
                   ToastUtil.showToast(getApplicationContext(), R.string.footer_net_error);
               }

});
```

I found that the Facebook class PlatformServiceClient has a null result here:

```
protected abstract void populateRequestBundle(Bundle data);

protected void handleMessage(Message message) {
    if (message.what == replyMessage) {
        Bundle extras = message.getData();
        String errorType = extras.getString(NativeProtocol.STATUS_ERROR_TYPE);
        if (errorType != null) {
            callback(null);
        } else {
            callback(extras);
        }
        context.unbindService(this);
    }
}
```

The extras is null.

Could someone help me? Thanks .

Comment: did you solve this? having a similar issue now.

Comment: same issue here, did you have any luck?

Comment: I think it's a bug in the facebook SDK. I created a new ticket: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/215715868808649/

Comment: Did you solve this issue? Some users of our app are reporting crashes.

Comment: Facing same issue. Did anyone get resolve?